# One line of code in TypeScript doc is hard to understand

Tags: typescript

Not sure if this is the right place to ask like this, but on this page:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#inference-with-template-literals

I have this line of code in one of the sample codes:

```
type PropEventSource<Type> = {
    on<Key extends string & keyof Type> // this line
        (eventName: `${Key}Changed`, callback: (newValue: Type[Key]) => void ): void;
};

declare function makeWatchedObject<Type>(obj: Type): Type & PropEventSource<Type>;
 
const person = makeWatchedObject({
  firstName: "Saoirse",
  lastName: "Ronan",
  age: 26
});
```

The second line is hard to understand. I asked one of the authors of the page, but no response yet. I think it should not have `string &` but then TypeScript reports error. the `keyof Type` should return the union of the property names as literals, right? Then why do we need `string &`?

Comment: `keyof Type` could also include `number` and `symbol` - https://tsplay.dev/NllQON.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but calling something "not understandable" just because you don't understand it is a bit inflammatory.

Comment: @pamphlet I think OP is saying that it is not understandable to them, plus English may not be their first language so it may not be worded exactly perfectly but you do get what is being asked here

Comment: @jonrsharpe: so then, `string & keyof Type` means that among keys of type Type, only keys of type string could become `Key` (since intersection means if `A & B`, the resulting type should have all properties of both A and B: so the resulting type should be at least of Type string, right?
Usually handbook is great at explaining critical/hard parts, but for this, there's been no explanation, so it was hard to understand for someone like me who just starts to learn TS. Thank you all!